# Linux Graphic Library for Microcontrollers

Tags: linux, gui, libraries, arm, microcontroller

I have been working with a lpc1788 (Cortex M3) evaluation board. For some application developement I used a GUI library/tool by Segger, called emWin.
Though I have completed the applicatiopn developement on keil uVision 4, I am keen to whether the same can be done on a linux gnu-arm toolchain used along with a GUI library.
As the name itself suggests, emWin is not meant for linux platform developement.
And, its costly too not being an open source.
Can anybody please inform me if there are any options available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of three options thus far:

1. Rely on a third-party product for your touchscreen that has a simple and platform independent implementation.  Best example in my opinion is the [Amulet](http://www.amulettechnologies.com/) touchscreen.  You design your GUI in HTML, and use their widgets for user-interactivity.  You just have to implement their simple serial protocol to be able to transfer data to and from the touchscreen.
2. Though I don't have personal experience with these options, I did look around a bit and saw an open source library called [eGUI](http://www.open-etech.com/Tech/eGUI/).  If you want to try it, there is are some old downloads out there... it looks like it is not really actively maintained, though.
3. Do it yourself.  I usually lean towards the solution that's ready to go out of the box, since the company can justify adding on a $200 touchscreen that offers all of the capability out of the box.  However, since it seems like you don't want recurring costs, you might want to roll your own.  I don't know if you need all of the features that emWin gives you, like VNC support.

Here's another related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366278/graphics-library-for-embedded-systems-without-linux